WPF Frame Navigation: Preventing Duplicate Instances in Navigation History
In my WPF application, I'm using a Frame for navigation between pages. The issue I'm encountering is that whenever I navigate to a page that is already open, a new instance of that page is added to the navigation history. This results in multiple instances of the same page being stored in the history, which I want to avoid.
This is what I want to avoid
The class that I use to navegate is this I tried to avoid it creating only one instance of the class but it dosn't work for my problem:
using System.Windows;

    public partial class MainPage : Window
    {
        public ClientWindow ClientsPage;
        public InvoiceWindow DraftInvoicePage;
        public InvoiceWindow IssuedInvoicePage;
        public InvoiceWindow SentInvoicePage;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainFrame.Navigate(new DefaultPage(this));
        }

        public void LoadClientsPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ClientsPage == null)
            {
                ClientsPage = new ClientWindow();
            }
            MainFrame.Navigate(ClientsPage);
        }

        public void LoadDraftInvoicesPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DraftInvoicePage == null)
            {
                DraftInvoicePage = new InvoiceWindow(InvoiceWindow.InvoiceType.Draft);
            }
            MainFrame.Navigate(DraftInvoicePage);
        }

        public void LoadIssuedInvoicesPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IssuedInvoicePage == null)
            {
                IssuedInvoicePage = new InvoiceWindow(InvoiceWindow.InvoiceType.Issued);
            }
            MainFrame.Navigate(IssuedInvoicePage);
        }

        public void LoadSentInvoicesPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SentInvoicePage == null)
            {
                SentInvoicePage = new InvoiceWindow(InvoiceWindow.InvoiceType.Sent);
            }
            MainFrame.Navigate(SentInvoicePage);
        }

        public void OpenConfiguration(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ConfigurationWindow configWindow = new ConfigurationWindow();
            configWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
    }




This is just how the navigation history works: the Frame tracks and remembers each navigation step. By default, the navigation history does not contain your page objects. They contain meta data that is used to populate the new instance that is created on navigation. If your concern is about memory then you can safely keep everything as it is. You explicitly set the attached property JournalEntry.KeepAlive to true (e.g. when you need to preserve the state of the navigation target).

You can't change the behavior of the history stack. However, you can manipulate the stack using the Frame.BackStack and Frame.ForwardStack properties along with Frame.AddBackEntry  and Frame.RemoveBackEntry to change the order or occurrence of the entries.
